# Display Text - Diplay Field

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I want to display a static text in my app which would be a tab in my tabpanel...

I can only find textfield with input... how do I get a textfield no input to show?

In sencha architect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for label component: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.Label

Since you clarified that this is for Sencha Touch and not ExtJs, the only way to do is to use standard Ext.Component element and specify `html` property of it.

Comment: I don't think so, label are for one single line of text.

I need to right a paragraph, it's a explanation page

Comment: create a `box` then and assign internal HTML to whatever you want

Comment: I dont have the ''box'' in sencha architect :(

Comment: There is also a display field: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display

Comment: Is it Sencha Touch or EXTJS ?

Comment: Both of you gave me EXTJS answer, I need sencha touch answer, the one I accepted was the write html inside somthing.  Which is to me kind of  ugly solution but works.

Comment: Would there be any better solution? It's kind of crappy imo to not have any "display component"